# Плавное появление UI элемента

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Как сделать плавное появление UI элемента?

Есть такой вот вариант :

```
 BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
                                    To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
        </Storyboard>
</BeginStoryboard>
```

В данном случае весь элемент будет отрисовыватся сразу, уменьшая Opacity от 0 до 1.

Как можно сделать чтобы контрол отрисовывался слева направо без Opacity?

Comment: Анимируйте Margin, например,

Comment: @VladD, можете маленький пример сделать? Идея в том что при изменении свойства в VM должен появиться контрол.

Comment: Сделал, пробуйте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего санимировать трансформацию. Например, так:

```
<Window x:Class="..."
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="Animation test" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Background="DeepSkyBlue">
            <Border.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowAdditionalUI}">
                            <DataTrigger.Value>
                                <sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean>
                            </DataTrigger.Value>
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            To="0" Duration="0:0:1"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="
                                                (UIElement.RenderTransform).
                                                (TranslateTransform.X)"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Duration="0:0:1"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="
                                                (UIElement.RenderTransform).
                                                (TranslateTransform.X)"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
            <Border.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform
                    X="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                        AncestorType=UIElement}}"/>
            </Border.RenderTransform>
            <TextBlock>Дополнительный выезжающий контент</TextBlock>
        </Border>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ShowAdditionalUI}" Grid.Row="1">
            Показать выезжающий контрол
        </CheckBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

(Обратите внимание, что в обратной анимации не указано `To`, так что смещение откатится к «нормальному» значению.)

---

«Невидимая» часть контрола должна быть ограничена контейнером этого контрола, и тем самым не видна. Если она у вас всё же видна, поместите `Border` во промежуточный контейнер с `ClipToBounds="True"`:

```
<Border ClipToBounds="True"> <!-- вот это добавляем -->
    <Border Background="DeepSkyBlue">
        ...
    </Border>
</Border>
```

---

Результат (скриншот в процессе анимации):

[image: анимация]

Comment: Стараюсь разобраться. Насколько я понимаю, то элемент видимый, просто он за пределами экрана и по нажатию выезжает. Но если мне нужно что бы он выехал не из-за пределов приложения, а допустим из центра приложения, то такой подход не подойдет ведь?

Comment: @Lightness: Почти так. Элемент прячется не за пределами окна, а за пределами своего _контейнера_ (в данном случае `Grid`). По идее, в середине окна должно точно так же работать.

Comment: я попробовал это сделать и элемент вылез за пределы своего контейнера.

Comment: @Lightness: Ага, понял, в чём у вас проблема. Заключите `Border` в ещё один внешний `Border` с `ClipToBounds="True"`: `<Border ClipToBounds="True"><Border Background="DeepSkyBlue">...</Border></Border>`. Сработало?

Comment: Сработало, спасибо!

Comment: @Lightness: Отлично, тогда дополню ответ.